# How to use MethodDecorator.Fody Decorator in another project

Tags: c#, nuget-package, fody

I used Fody Nuget package as follows

1. Install package

   ```
   PM> Install-Package MethodDecorator.Fody
   ```
2. Decorate the method

   ```
   public class BusinessLayerClass
   {
       [LogMethod] 
       public string BusinessLayerMethod()
       {
           DataLayerClass dataLayerClass = new DataLayerClass();
          return  dataLayerClass.DataLayerMethod();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Write the interceptor

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;

   [module: LogMethod] // Attribute should be "registered" by adding as module or assembly custom attribute

   // Any attribute which provides OnEntry/OnExit/OnException with proper args
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Module)]
   public class LogMethodAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
   {
       private MethodBase _method;

       // instance, method and args can be captured here and stored in attribute instance fields
       // for future usage in OnEntry/OnExit/OnException

       public void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args)
       {
           _method = method;
       }

       public void OnEntry()
       {
           NLogging.Trace("Entering into {0}", _method.Name);
       }

       public void OnExit()
       {
           NLogging.Trace("Exiting into {0}", _method.Name);
       }

       public void OnException(Exception exception)
       {
           NLogging.Trace(exception, "Exception {0}", _method.Name);
       }
   }
   ```

---

This works fine within the same project but when I use the decorator [LogMethod] in another method in another project, this `OnEntry()`, `OnExit()`, `OnException(Exception exception)` methods do not fire.

For instance:

```
[LogMethod]
public void Another_Method_In_Seperate_Project()
```

I added a reference to the project where [LogMethod] is defined.

Could anyone please send me a way of using the same implementation in other projects without doing the implementation of LogMethodAttribute.cs (where this [LogMethod] is defined) in each and every project.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `MethodDecorator.Fody` nuget package in the other project as well (along with dependencies). You will also need to add another `FodyWeavers.xml` in that project.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by H.D. I recommend looking at this answer, from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503942/13081132

Edit:
The answer I have linked to simply reminds the author to "register" the attribute inside the file where the attributes is being used.

Example:

```
[module: LogMethod] // In my case this was nessesary for all files using the attribute

public class BusinessLayerClass
{
    [LogMethod] 
    public string BusinessLayerMethod()
    {
        DataLayerClass dataLayerClass = new DataLayerClass();
       return  dataLayerClass.DataLayerMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, right. But is there a way not to use this `[module]` in every file?

Comment: Yeah, right. But is there a way not to use this `[module]` in every files?